# Magento sub-categories URL redirects to 404

Tags: php, magento

Magento Version: 1.8 CE

I have 2 stores: Store 1 and Store 2

Store 1's root category has sub categories A, B and C

I wanted Store 2 to list all the sub-categories from Store A(ie A, B and C)

This is the code I am using now:

```
$_rootCatId     = 7;
$_rootCategory  = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_rootCatId);
$collection = $_rootCategory->getChildrenCategories();
$helper     = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
foreach ($collection as $cat) {
if($cat->getIsActive()==1)
    {
        echo $cat->getURL();
        echo $cat->getName();
    }
}
```

This lists all the subcategories, but the corresponding URLs redirect to 404.

However, if I change the root category of Store 2 to the same as Store 1, it gives the same URL and is listing all the products. Is this because magento restricts access to those sub-categories which does not come under the root category of the current store?

I am new to magento and wanted to know if this is possible, i.e listing all the products within another store's sub-category.

Comment: I overrode the canShow() function in catalog/category helper to ignore isRootCategory() and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overrode the canShow() function in catalog/category helper to ignore isRootCategory() and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding store filter to your $_rootCategory. e.g.

```
$_rootCategory  = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(1)->load($_rootCatId);
```

Comment: What if I have  not assigned the category as the root category of any store? Then is it possible to get the products within that category?